# How can I add data from a DataTable to a database table directly without specific prior structure in database table?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I want to create table in database I got from excel I had tried sqlbulkcopy and many ways but they all require the fix structure in database before writing datatable is it possible to create table in database as per datatable without priror specification?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SqlServer Management Objects (SMO) might be the answer to your problem. It will allow you to dynamically create db and table. I am not an expert in this area, but the following article will hel you understand how to implement this.

[Copy Data from a DataTable to a SQLServer Database using SQLServer Management Objects and SqlBulkCopy](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17169/Copy-Data-from-a-DataTable-to-a-SQLServer-Database)